# Battery showing empty after replacement

Tags: power-management, laptop, indicator, battery

I have a Razer Blade and my battery kind of went kaput so I bought a new one from ebay and replaced it. Before my laptop would just randomly shut off anywhere from 5-15 minutes after turning it on even though the battery showed fulled, now the laptop works perfectly fine on battery except that the battery shows empty in the task bar, red light on the computer itself and upower shows that it has a 0% capacity. I am assuming the laptop is not reading something from the battery correctly?

I also booted into a live usb of ubuntu and the battery shows the same 0% indicator.

Is there something that needs to be recent when changing a battery or something like that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first thing to try is removing the battery and putting it back in again. Sometimes they don't get a good physical connection to the laptop.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I just tried to reseat the connectors and that did not work. it is still showing as empty.